# Event loop and compute-intensive tasks problems with node > 0.8

Tags: node.js, express, event-handling

What I want to do is to add a REST server on top of the evolutionary algorithm I have in [NodEO](http://npmjs.org/nodeo). I am following [these steps](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick) which basically means

```
app.listen(port)
do_compute_intensive_task()
```

and then

```
function do_compute_intensive_task() {
  do_lots_of_stuff();
  if (not_finished) {
     process.nextTick(do_compute_intensive_task());
  } else {
     console.log("We're done" );
  }
}
```

It's checked in (I know, I shouldn't) [here](https://github.com/JJ/nodeo/blob/master/app/trap-rest.js). The compute-intensive part runs pretty well, but the REST server does not answer, it stalls the connection until the intensive part finishes. I've installed the very last, node v0.10.24 and it does not work. Here's the `uname -a`

```
Linux penny 3.8.0-35-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:24:59 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It works, though, in another machine with a different version of node and a slower processor: version is v0.8.18, the processor is a i5 and `uname -a` returns

```
Linux amy 3.8.0-35-generic #50~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 17:25:51 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Question is now: What am I doing wrong? Anything? Something? Is it a bug? Does it have something to do with processor speed?

*Update* I have installed `nave` (and you should, too) to check with different versions, and it stopped working somewhere in the 0.9 version. It works with the last version of 0.8 (0.8.26), it no longer works with the latest 0.9 or with the latest 0.11.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it's been answered [in the nodejs issues queue (and quite fast)](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6927). `process.nextTick` gives priority to compute-intensive events. If you want them to wait for io, use `setImmediate`. Fixed in [this commit to nodeo](https://github.com/JJ/nodeo/commit/3407fa56cc7ecad8b046e3ba0f69773c841e4773)

Answer (score 1):

The node community voted that use of `process.nextTick()` off the island. For your reading enjoyment:

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3335

Comment: Whyowhy? At least there's a reasonable replacement. Thanks!